# An event listener is (presumably) not removed properly. (JavaScript + HTML)

Tags: javascript, button, events, listener

I've written this code:

https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/b4c32b9c6e77462bb2fc322da4059bbe

Everything works fine on the first image, but if the next image has another solution (istrue) as the previous, both answers are correct. I think the EventListener isn't full removed, isn't it?

Best regards

Comment: Please remove irrelevant code from your snippet and put scripts and styles in its proper places.

Comment: I edited and removed the html :)

Comment: That's not what I meant at all. Please add a snippet with relevant code only, and JS and CSS in the proper boxes.